# Can't install Ubuntu on a HP DV6 Laptop

Tags: installation, kubuntu, dv6, hp-pavilion

I just bought a HP DV6 6011tx ([link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=5075390&lc=en&cc=sg&dlc=en&lang=en&tmp_track_link=ot_we/prodlink/en_sg/5075390/loc:0&cc=sg)) Laptop. I formated the disk through Windows and prepared for installing Ubuntu. But when I inserted the live CD, it showed the Ubuntu start screen and then everything went black. There was no cursor, everything just stayed black like the screen was switched off (but the system is running).

When I tried to install from the USB, it said `Live media is not found`. Sometimes it also gave me a black screen like the CD. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the alternate CD, it has non graphics installer.

Comment: try redownloading the iso image and burning it again. and see if it works. try loading a different OS and see if the same thing comes up if its same see maybe there is smthn in the bios. hope this helps.

Comment: Checked the Hash and the ISO have no errors!

Comment: if its possible can u provide us with a video of booting the live cd. it will help us figure out the problem faster. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with my HP Envy 14.

Press any key when the small logo appears at the bottom to enter the advanced start page.
Then press <kbd>F6</kbd> for other options (but don't select anything), press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to the Boot Options line. There you should add

```
radeon.modeset=0
```

Now you can install Ubuntu and as soon as the screen goes dark simply press the brightness key <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Worked for me :)

Comment: This solved my issue with my HP DV6. What gave you the indication to do this?

Comment: note that if you modified your function keys so the default is a function key rather than the extended hp functions, you will need to press fn+F3. I wasted 20 minutes because I stupidly forgot I had done this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the alternate installation. In the options screen, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to add further Linux boot parameters and add `acpi=off`.

Answer (score 1):

Press the brightness key on your computer which is <kbd>F3</kbd>. The problem is the brightness is so low that it's off.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** (issue with USB)

Insert USB stick, and reboot laptop.

Stop the boot (at BIOS logo), with <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or as prompted), and select USB as boot source.

If Ubuntu install immediately stops with error, type <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>; wait 4 seconds, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***If that fails, then try ..***

**Option 2:** (issue with GUI install)

Use the '**Alternate install CD** (on CD or USB) instead ..

http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download (location near you)

Then your PC should tell you what the issue is, instead of just stalling ..